# <render-mode> not working with dynamic Material UI

Tags: moqui

I use the <render-mode> tag to include some html in my screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<screen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://moqui.org/xsd/xml-screen-2.1.xsd"
    require-authentication="anonymous-all">
<widgets>
    <label type="h1" text="Hello world!"/>
    <render-mode>
        <text type="html,vuet" location="component://tutorial/template/hello.html"/>
    </render-mode>
    <label type="h1" text="after Hello world!"/>
</widgets>
</screen>
```

The incuded hello.html file is shown fine using the "standard UI" or "dynamic Bootstrap UI", but it doesn't show when using the "dynamic Material UI".
Is there a way to enable this? I much prefer the look and navigation of the dynamic Material UI.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't show under qapps is that qapps uses a new render mode 'qvt' just like vapps uses the render mode 'vuet'. To make it show under /qapps just change:

```
<text type="html,vuet" ...
```

to:

```
<text type="html,vuet,qvt" ...
```